# why am I getting imaginary numbers instead of a simple answer

Tags: matlab

this is just part of the code that matters and needs to be fixed. I don't know what i'm doing wrong here. all the variables are simple numbers, it's true that one is needed for that other, but there shouldn't be anything wrong with that. the answer for which I'm getting imaginary numbers is supposed to be part of a loop, so it's important I get it right. please ignore the variables that are not needed, as i just wrote a part of the code

the answer i get is:

KrInitialFirstPart = 0.000000000000000e+00 - 1.466747615972368e+05i

```
clear all;
clc;
% the initial position components
rInitial= 10; %kpc
zInitial= 0; %kpc
% the initial velocity components
vrInitial= 0; %km/s
vzInitial= 150; %tangential velocity component
vtInitial= 150; %not used
% the height
h= rInitial*vzInitial; %angulan momentum constant
tInitial=0;
Dt=1e-3;

    e=0.99;
    pc=11613.5;

    KrInitialFirstPart= -4*pi*pc*sqrt( 1-(e^2) / (e^3) )*rInitial
    format long
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
sqrt( 1-(e^2) / (e^3) )
```

you have here

```
e=0.99;
```

so e < 1 and so e^3 is less than e^2.

Therefore

```
(e^2)/(e^3) > 1.
```

The division operation binds tighter than (i.e is evaluated ahead of) the subtraction so you are taking a square root of a negative number. Hence the imaginary component in your result.

Perhaps you require

```
sqrt( (1-(e^2)) / (e^3) )
```

which is guaranteed to yield a real number result since

```
 1 - e^2 > 0
```

for your specified `e`